# How to generate a rails view with javascript (in a view.js.erb)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In the client side, the browser sends an ajax request like so:

```
link_to( "#{sir.sir_id}", "results/#{sir.id}", remote: true, format: :js ),
```

which is processed on the server side by my controller's `show action` as `JS`:

```
  def show
    @sir_id = params[:id]
    @spectrum_identification_items = SpectrumIdentificationResult.find(@sir_id).spectrum_identification_items
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js { } 
    end
  end
```

So this is processed correctly so far. Now I create a `show.js.erb` with a one-line content:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript render(file: 'spectrum_identification_results/show.haml') %>").appendTo('table#sii_table');
```

which is expected to render the content of my show view, (has only some plain text to test)

So the server does not show any error:

```
Rendered spectrum_identification_results/show.haml (0.4ms)
Rendered spectrum_identification_results/show.js.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms
```

and when making the call non-ajax and rendering html I can check the content of the show action is processed correctly...

Also I don't see no javascript errors in the chrome inspector

However the content of the show view file is not appearing anywhere ?

What am I missing here?

Comment: you have missed `.` before `appendTo`

Comment: yes, missed that, but still does not work. The content of show.haml does not appear anywhere

Comment: What's in the JS console and the network log?

Comment: the JS console does not show any error and the network log shows a `200 OK` result when I click on the ajax link

Comment: I see, in the network log, (in chrome inspector), that there is a javascript response that generates a file (response 200 OK) But in the preview of that file, I see that the content of `show.haml` is not appended where I intend, but placed in a content tag : `      <content>$("o sea, hello?").appendTo('table#sii_table');</content>`

Comment: Do I have to add an event handler in assets/javascripts/the_right_controller.js.coffee to watch ajax success or something like that?